# Executing an external .exe with Php exec()

Tags: php, permissions, command, exec, exe

I've a problem of using `exec()` function properly. I've a external executable file and I can run it from my user in the device and it's acting normal but with PHP `exec()` function it's not acting normal.

Details;

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 Kas 18 07:41 .
drwxr-xr-x. 27 root root     4096 Eyl 21 04:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11169253 Kas 18 06:43 example.exe
```

it's OK with this command as a user, and it can create out file.

```
/srv/example.exe 'examplefile.tmp' '/srv/exampleout.tmp'
```

However when i used the same command with php exec() function, it seems that worked succesfully but, cannot create the out file.

```
exec("/srv/example.exe 'examplefile.tmp' '/srv/exampleout.tmp'", $op, $ret);
```

With this way,

```
$op = empty array
$ret = int 1
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What does that funny file name extension `.exe` do in a unix like system?

Comment: most likely you are facing a file permission problem. Keep in mind that when running a php script inside a http server then the process started by `exec()` runs under the account and rights profile of the http process. That account most likely does not have write permissions for `/srv`.

Comment: Thank you, how could i give write permission to http process for srv/? i only tried "chmod 755 srv/" command.

Comment: You should not store runtime files at that location. Use a specific folder for that and grant write access via the group membership of the http server process.